# String from address in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, pointers, dll, memory-address

In my VB.NET application I use a function from a .dll that shall give me a string. 
When calling the function the Callback gives me the lenght of that string and an address instead of the string itself.

I tried to get the string with this code but I think it was meant for VB classic, not for VB.NET:

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal Destination As Object, ByVal Source As Object, ByVal Length As Long)
Private Declare Function lstrlenA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString As Long) As Long

Private Function pvToString(ByVal lPtr As Long) As String
    If lPtr <> 0 Then
    pvToString = String(lstrlenA(lPtr), 0)
    Call CopyMemory(ByVal pvToString, ByVal lPtr, Len(pvToString))
    End If
End Function
```

I get 4 Errors and I don't know how to get rid of them:

1. '.' expected (for line 5 for String)
2. 'String' is a class type and can not be used as an expression (for line 5)
3. Expression expected (for line 6 for ByVal)
4. Expression expected (for line 6 for ByVal)

Sorry, if my question is stupid. I'm a starter in programming and VB.NET

Comment: What I can help you with: Remove the `ByVal`s.

Comment: Full example of how to use this is here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon/CopyMemory.html

Comment: After looking at a VB6 documentation, the `String()` function just creates a string filled with the specified amount of a certain character. You should be able to remove this line without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

First about errors:
1 and 2:  use new String(' ',len) instead.
3 and 4: remove `call` and `ByVal`
and all `Long` variables and argument must be declare as integer expect `lstrlen` that should be declare as IntPtr.
anyway you should forget all. if you have a pointer (IntPtr) and you want to convert it to string, depending to your string type you can easily use:
    dim myString as string= System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStrXXXX(MyPSZString)

Comment: I used your Marshal suggestion. Now I get Chinese characters instead of Roman characters. That's quite weird because the source string is in Roman letters.:D Any ideas?

Comment: I used Marshal.PtrToStrAuto()

Comment: Did `PtrToStrAuto` resolved problem? try BStr and Uni versions. can you insert your unmanaged function signature?

Comment: PtrToStrAuto didn't solve the problem. Same thing with Uni. BStr gives me an error saying "You tried to read or write in protected memory. Mostly this is a hint that other memory is spoilt." (translated from German into Englisch)

Comment: The Documentation about the function I'm trying to use says this:
"BOOL XC_CommGetProjectNameFromPLC(ULONG ulChannel )

Function: Get the projectname from plc. If there is no project loaded  the funtions returns 1 in Arg3 . The stringpointer in Arg4 points to a 0x00.
Returnwert: TRUE  if Success
FALSE if not STATE_IDLE or COMM_BAD_CHANNEL
Callback: Arg1: STATE_PINF
  Arg2: Channelnumber
  Arg3: Stringlength +1  (terminating 0)
  Arg4: Pointer to String
"

Comment: So I did this:
 <DllImport("XC_Comm.DLL", EntryPoint:="XC_CommGetProjectNameFromPLC",
   SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi,
   ExactSpelling:=True,
   CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
    Public Shared Function XC_CommGetProjectNameFromPLC(ByVal ulChannel As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

Answer (score -3):

Looks like your declaration should be something like

```
Private Declare Function lstrlenA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString As Long) As String
```

instead of

```
Private Declare Function lstrlenA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString As Long) As Long
```

Sorry have no access to visual studio right now to test this. But looks like this is where it is going wrong.

PS: declaration might be wrong for the other function too. try removing ByVal

Comment: why -vote? This might be a better answer for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921852/how-to-get-the-string-from-an-address-specified-by-a-long-in-vb

Comment: You probably got a downvote because what you're saying is incorrect. Infact it should actually be `Integer`: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.lstrlen - **Also**, the link you gave him is almost exactly the same code that he uses, meaning it won't work.

Comment: Also, `ByVal` doesn't make the declaration incorrect. If you don't use `ByVal` it will be added by default by the compiler. I think those two points explain the downvote.